# Issue with options of the marked library for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-marked

I use Marked library in a React project and would like to set the option "gfm: true" and "breaks: true".

Based on [example](https://marked.js.org/using_advanced#options) provided on the official website I think I am doing the right thing but the changes do not appear on my project.

I have put the two solutions below but none of them works.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    [textToMarkdown(), markdownText]
})

    const [markdowned, setMarkdowned] = React.useState("")



    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setMarkdownText(e.target.value)
        textToMarkdown()
    }

    // https://marked.js.org/using_advanced
    marked.setOptions({
        gfm: true,
        breaks: true,
        xhtml: true
      });

    const textToMarkdown = () => {
        setMarkdowned(marked.parse(markdownText, {breaks: true, gfm: true}));
    }
```

Comment: **All: I think it's just a typo-level error.** Reggroy, `React.useEffect(() => { [textToMarkdown(), markdownText] })` is unlikely to be correct. That's a call to `useEffect` passing in a function that creates an array (including making a function call) and then throws it away. The callback will be called every time, because there's no dependency array. Did you mean `React.useEffect(() => {  textToMarkdown(); }, [markdownText]);` or `React.useEffect(textToMarkdown, [markdownText]);`? ...

Comment: ... That calls `useEffect` passing a function that will call `textToMarkdown()` (or passing `textToMarkdown` directly) and a dependency array with `markdownText` in it, so the effect runs every time `markdownText` changes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, there was a typo in the useEffect and I just removed the markdown text which was useless in that case. However, it doesn't change the options of the Marked library regarding the return carriage.